# How can i retrieve an image of <img> tag into the variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can i get the image of the `<img>` tag and store it in a variable in javascript (or equivalently jquery) ?

(actually i want to swap the images between two `<img>` tags).

Comment: get the attribute src.$('#imageid').attr('src');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has specific uses for .prop() vs .attr() so make sure to read up on that:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/

But once you assigned the src of one image to a variable:

```
var img1_src = $("img#image1").attr("src");
```

You can then take that variable and shove it into the source of another image:

```
$('img#img2').attr('src', img1_src);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could assign `id` for the image , and do:

```
var img_src = document.getElementById("your_image_id").src;
```

or with jQuery

```
var img_src = $("img#your_image_id").prop("src");
```

Comment: I thought it was the .attr() method ?

Comment: @PeterFour see:: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @Sudhir `.prop()` is for *properties*, `.attr()` is for *attributes*. You ought to use .attr() in your example.

Comment: @Sudhir: doesn't it make the browser to request for the images from the web server again ?!

Comment: @Shnd no it doesnot, it just returns the source of image from DOM element

Comment: Thank you, it's my answer, but actually you should use attr() function, but i got my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use attr() or prop() to get the src of an image tag.
Like this

```
$('#imageId').attr('src');
```

Check [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var src = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery attr attribute to get the src attribute of your image

```
<img src="#" class="my_img"></img>

var img = $('.my_img').attr('src');
```

Note styles applied through id attribute are not applicable to img tags

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with JavaScript preferably using the two images IDs.

```
var img1_src = document.getElementById("img1_id").src;

document.getElementById("img2_id").src = img1_src;
```

Comment: As OP wants to swap images, this is missing a second assignment, i.e. `var img2_src = document.getElementById('img2_id').src; document.getElementById('img1_id').src = img2_src;`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The second part mirrors the first.